# How one can implement the equation with "$i$" in it?

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, exponential-function

I have an equation:
$$f(t)=c(e^{i2\pi\frac{n}{T}t}+e^{-i2\pi\frac{n}{T}t})$$
...for $t\in(-\pi,\pi)$, and with $T=2\pi$.
I have to draw a plot of the function $f(t)$ for $n\in\left \{0,1,2,5  \right \}$. But my question is - how can I express $i$ and $-i$ in my code (I'm writing in Python)? What is e.g the total value of the power $i2\pi\frac{n}{T}t$ for $n=1$ and $T=2$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $e^{ia}+e^{-ia}=2\cos(a)$ could help

Comment: So I can write $f(t)=c(2cos(2\pi\frac{n}{T}t))$?

Comment: Yes, for sure ... as already told in answers. Always keep in mind Euler identities. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 
$$
\cos(\theta) = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{i\theta} + \mathrm{e}^{-i\theta}}{2}
$$
I can rewrite your equation as
$$
f(t) = 2c\cos\left(2\pi\frac{n}{T}t\right)
$$
which is easier to plot, no?

As for the power calculation, what you have written doesn’t make sense. You can compute the power of $f(t)$ as 
$$
\int_{\Omega} |f(t)|^2dt
$$
where $\Omega$ is the domain of interest.

Answer (score 3):

Use $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$ and compute the real and imaginary parts separatedly. Note that the imaginary parts cancel out.